# How to correctly compute rotation in 3D Procrustes Problem if there is a translation added?

Tags: 3d, rotation, svd

I am developing a routine that should optimally align a sensed 3D point cloud **Q**  with respect to a reference point cloud **P**. The transformation involved includes rotation, translation and scaling (a similarity). There exists a great amount of literature about how to compute the transformation using SVD. I have been following this one: *R. J. Hanson and M. J. Norris, “Analysis of measurements based on the singular value decomposition,” SIAM Journal on Scientiﬁc and Statistical Computing, vol. 2, pp. 363–373, 1981.*

The algorithm described is as follows: calculate centroids in each point set, compute the centered point sets; compute the covariance matrix between the two centered point sets and perform the SVD on the covariance matrix : **C = U * S * V'**, where **C** is the covariance matrix, **S** the diagonal matrix of its singular values, **U** and **V** the left and right singular vector matrices, respectively. Then you can compute the rotation component of the transformation as **R = U' * V**.

This algorithm works for me perfectly if the transformation consists of a rotation and (optionally) a scaling, but if there is a translation present, it fails. I have so far not understood what it is I am doing wrongly. I also failed to find any usable numerical examples that would include translation and lead to a success.

I would also upload my code if someone would like to have a look.

Comment: I have done this before. The theory is correct, so there must be a bug somewhere in the implementation. I would like to see the code.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, you may be right, and I am revising the code at the moment. I will eagerly show it to you, then!

Comment: Mauricio, I found the error: it was in the 'scaling' bit: when you compute the translation vector, you need to calculate the scaling first and then use the rotation matrix MULTIPLIED with the pure rotation matrix, otherwise the translation vector so computed will be wrong. However, it took me hours to find it out.

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon I have gained some new experiences with the algorithm, namely, if the number of the point pairs is less or equal to three, some strange instability randomly occurs: if I am taking nearly identical source and target points, the computed transformation is sometimes correct (unity matrix), but sometimes quite wrong (e.g. -1, 1, -1, 1 on the diagonal). I have also remarked that one of the eigenvalues of the SVD is zero. If I take 4 point pairs or more, this seems not to happen. I always thought 3 point pairs would be enough. Is anything known to this point?

Comment: @AlexKonnen it is needed to fix the sign of the last eigenvector as described in Kabsch algorithm: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm but beyond that, there are degenerate cases like for two vector case if both vectors are colinear then there are infinitely many solutions. However that is infrequent. But since you said the issues are not rare cases, I would tend to think that the SVD algorithm you are using is introducing the instabilities.

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon Thanks for your comments, they do help. It is probably a good idea to question the SVD routine. I am using that of MathNet.Numerics which I have also exhaustively and positively unit tested before. However, I have a set of three non-coplanar vector pairs that produce the instability. My "empirical" decision was that to increase the minimum number of points needed to four. According to my observation, no instability happens with 4 points or more, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 0):

As Mauricio Cele Lopez Belon correctly supposed, it was a bug, however, rather a thinking error. Whenever you have a non-unit scaling in the similarity transformation, to compute the translation vector you need to use the rotation matrix multiplied with the scaling: 
**t** = **qC** - s * **R** * **pC**, where **pC** and **qC** are the centroids of the reference and the sensed point sets, respectively, **R** the computed pure rotation matrix, *s* scaling. You need to use this equation instead of **t** = **qC** - **R** * **pC** (which you often find in papers), to obtain correct results. If someone is interested in working and unit-tested C# code, I will be pleased to send ( a bit too long for this place).